# App gets crashed randomly while scrolling expandable list view

Tags: java, android

I've been recyclerview in my app and on scrolling it gets crashed, not under any certain use case..it just gets crashed randomly. Below is my adapter and View Holder code.

```
class CustomListView_Base_Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomListView_Base_Adapter(Context context) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return dataforSubcategoryItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return dataforSubcategoryItem.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return dataforSubcategoryItem.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View resultView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (resultView == null) {
            resultView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_subcategory_list_item, null); //TODO change layout id
            holder = new ViewHolder(resultView);
            resultView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) resultView.getTag();
        }
        final SubcategoryItemBean beanObj = (SubcategoryItemBean) getGroup(groupPosition);
        holder.tvColumnTitle.setText(beanObj.getName());
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);


        CustomWatcher oldWatcher = (CustomWatcher) holder.etInput.getTag();
        if (oldWatcher != null)
            holder.etInput.removeTextChangedListener(oldWatcher);

        if (beanObj.isColumnSelected()) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            holder.etInput.setText(dataforSubcategoryItem.get(groupPosition).getLabel());
            holder.etInput.setEnabled(true);
            listView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            holder.etInput.setText("");
            holder.etInput.setEnabled(false);
            listView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
        }


        CustomWatcher newWatcher = new CustomWatcher(groupPosition, holder.etInput);
        holder.etInput.setTag(newWatcher);
        holder.etInput.addTextChangedListener(newWatcher);
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    dataforSubcategoryItem.get(groupPosition).setColumnSelected(true);
                } else {
                    dataforSubcategoryItem.get(groupPosition).setColumnSelected(false);

                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        return resultView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View resultView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;


        if (resultView == null) {
            resultView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_list_item, null); //TODO change layout id
            holder = new ViewHolder(resultView, context);
            resultView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) resultView.getTag();
        }
        final SubcategoryItemBean beanObj = (SubcategoryItemBean) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        CustomWatcher oldWatcher = (CustomWatcher) holder.defaultValues.getTag();
        if (oldWatcher != null)
            holder.defaultValues.removeTextChangedListener(oldWatcher);
        holder.radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        holder.defaultValues.setText(beanObj.getValue());
        if (beanObj.getInput_type().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.column_type_text))) {
            holder.defaultValues.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            holder.defaultValues.setHint("Enter Default Value");
            holder.rbText.setChecked(true);
        } else if (beanObj.getInput_type().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.column_type_number))) {
            holder.defaultValues.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            holder.defaultValues.setHint("Enter Default Value");
            holder.rbNumber.setChecked(true);
        } else if (beanObj.getInput_type().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.column_type_radiobutton))) {
            holder.defaultValues.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            holder.defaultValues.setHint("Enter comma separated values");
            holder.rbRadioButton.setChecked(true);
        } else if (beanObj.getInput_type().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.column_type_checkbox))) {
            holder.rbCheckbox.setChecked(true);
            holder.defaultValues.setHint("Enter comma separated values");

            holder.defaultValues.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        } else {
            holder.rbDropdown.setChecked(true);
            holder.defaultValues.setHint("Enter comma separated values");
            holder.defaultValues.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        }


        holder.radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
                RadioButton button = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                dataforSubcategoryItem.get(groupPosition).setInput_type(button.getText().toString());
                holder.defaultValues.setText("");
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        CustomWatcher newWatcher = new CustomWatcher(groupPosition, holder.defaultValues);
        holder.defaultValues.setTag(newWatcher);
        holder.defaultValues.addTextChangedListener(newWatcher);
        return resultView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    private class CustomWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private int position;
        private EditText editText;

        private CustomWatcher(int position, EditText editText) {
            this.position = position;
            this.editText = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editText.getId() == R.id.addCategory_chooseItem_EditText) {
                dataforSubcategoryItem.get(position).setLabel(editable.toString().trim());
                System.out.println("CustomWatcher.onTextChanged   label" + editable.toString());
            }
            if (editText.getId() == R.id.defaultValues_addSubCategory_chooseItem) {
                dataforSubcategoryItem.get(position).setValue(editable.toString().trim());
                System.out.println("CustomWatcher.afterTextChanged default value " + editable.toString());
            }

        }
    }
}


class ViewHolder {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView tvColumnTitle;
    EditText etInput;
    RadioGroup radiogroup;
    RadioButton rbText, rbNumber, rbRadioButton, rbCheckbox, rbDropdown;
    EditText defaultValues;
    LinearLayout columnDetailsLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.addCategory_chooseItem_Checkbox);
        tvColumnTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addCategory_chooseItem_TextView);
        etInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addCategory_chooseItem_EditText);
    }

    public ViewHolder(View view, Context context) {
        columnDetailsLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.columnDetailsLayout);
        radiogroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup_addSubCategory_chooseItem);
        rbText = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbText_addSubCategory_chooseItem);
        rbNumber = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbNumber_addSubCategory_chooseItem);
        rbRadioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbRadioButton_addSubCategory_chooseItem);
        rbCheckbox = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbCheckbox_addSubCategory_chooseItem);
        rbDropdown = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbDropdown_addSubCategory_chooseItem);

        defaultValues = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.defaultValues_addSubCategory_chooseItem);

        rbText.setChecked(true);
    }


}
```

This is the output:

[image]

This is the error I'm getting after app gets crashed

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: global.edios.inventorymanagementtabletapp, PID: 2927
                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at android.widget.ExpandableListView.drawDivider(ExpandableListView.java:536)
                                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3288)
                                                                                         at android.widget.ExpandableListView.dispatchDraw(ExpandableListView.java:353)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
                                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4110)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                                         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
                                                                                         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
                                                                                         at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy, the app was crashed due to divider used in expandable view .. i removed the divider from expandable list and added a custom view instead of divider in

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_SelectAll"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
     />
```

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

This crash has occurred due to Expandable List View and invoking Text Watcher.
and using multiple Text Watcher's for both parent and child item.
Plus you even change Radio Group.

Try Changing text Watcher with Something else

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ..tried that but didn't really work